# Regular Expression for replacing string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I write regular expression to remove double dash -- into single dash - and if string start or end with dash replace with empty string.

```
var oldString = "abc--xyz--"
var filtered = oldStringt.replace(???????);
```

Sample Input >>>> Output

```
abc--xyz--       >>>>>    abc-xyz
abc---xyz-123    >>>>>    abc-xyz-123
--abc-xyz-123    >>>>>    abc-xyz-123
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about chaining replaces:

```
str.replace(/[-]+/g, '-').replace(/[-]+$/g, '').replace(/^[-]+/g, '')
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/MZhS4/).

Comment: Upvote!  No need for the square brackets, though (at least not in my console JS interpreter).

Comment: Why compile and execute 3 regexp’s when only one is needed?

Answer (score 2):

```
oldString.replace(/-+/g,"-").replace(/(^-+)|(-+$)/g,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single regexp that should work:

```
oldString.replace(/^-+|-+$|(-)+/g, '$1')
```

Tests: http://jsfiddle.net/kd9g3/

Now, I know you specifically asked for regexp, but many replaces like this one can be done using arrays as well (and sometimes they are faster):

```
oldString.split(/-+/).filter(function(e){return !!e}).join('-')
```